# Div is not taking 100% height of a table-cell in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, height

**HTML**

```
<li class="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 image">
            <div class="details-hover">
                <a href="#" class="vertical-align">Read more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="images/3245675.jpg" alt="image" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 description">
            <div class="details">
                <div class="date-and-likes">
                    <div class="date">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        <p class="">27 Oct</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="likes vertical-align">
                        <i class="icon-heart"></i>
                        <p>12</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#" class="d-text-c">Service &#38; Support on the iPhone 6. reviews and guide</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="author-and-coments">
                    <div class="author">
                        <p>By <a href="#">Admin</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comments">
                        <i class="icon-bubbles"></i>
                        <p>2 comments</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="preview">
                <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray...</p>
                <div class="read-more">
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.post-section .post {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  display: table;
}
.post-section .post .image,
.post-section .post .description {
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.post-section .post .description {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.post-section .post .row {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.post-section .post .image {
  position: relative;
}
.post-section .image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.post-section .post .image img {
  height: 100%;
}
.post-section .post .image .details-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.post-section .post .image .details-hover {
  z-index: 33;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I need to create a post list with an image on the left side and the content on the right. The problem is that Chrome, Opera and Firefox are rendering this code as needed but IE does not.

Here are some pictures.

[image: Chrome, Firefox and Opera]
[image: Internet Explorer]

Comment: How do you mean render as needed?

Comment: that blue container you see in Explorer needs to be 100% in height, in Chrome and others it is, but not in IE

Comment: What blue container? I tried to recreate the problem but to no avail  because it doesn't even come close to looking like you image sample.

Comment: .details-hover must be 100% of the height of the red container

Answer (score 0):

On Your:

```
<div class="details-hover" style="border: 1px solid blue; border-image:none;"<...</div
```

You need to set the value of `height: 100%;` in Internet explorer.

Comment: it's written in the css, is there a problem with display: table-cell in internet explorer? i can't figuring out why this happens